# How to unsubscribe from an event inside of the gamemanager?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, delegates, singleton

In my `GameManager` script I have a delegate. In my `Door` script, I subscribe to this delegate. I've tried unsubscribing from it in both the `OnDisable` and `OnDestroy` methods in the `Door` script. In both cases, I get an error when I stop running the game in the editor:

> Some objects were not cleaned up when closing the scene. (Did you spawn new GameObjects from OnDestroy?)

Using `Debug.Log`, I found out that this is because the `GameManager` will always be destroyed before the `Door` script. Even if I do a `null` check inside either the `OnDisable` or `OnDestroy` of the `Door` script to see if the `GameManager` is `null`, I get the same error

```
if (GameManager.Instance)
{
    GameManager.Instance.OnAllEnemiesKilled -= OpenDoor;
}
```

Somebody told me that I don't need to unsubscribe from it, as the delegate will automatically become null when the `Door` object is destroyed, but that's not true. During runtime, after the `Door` is destroyed, my update loop inside of the `GameManager` is still printing that the delegate has one subscriber: the `Door`.

Comment: There might be several instances of Door and GameManager, even though it looks like there is only one. Do a debug check on the event and see how many subscribers it has. You're probably subscribing the Door multiple times without knowing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lece pointed out, I'm spawning a new singleton when I call GameManager.Instance. Rather than creating a static bool to remedy the problem however, I replaced `if (_instance == null)` with   `if ((object)_instance == null)` inside my Instance getter and it solved the problem. This is because, while the object is destroyed in the native code, it still exists in the managed code. So I'm now referencing it in the managed world. Moreover, Unity makes it so that when an object is destroyed in native code, its value in managed code will still return null.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're spawning a new singleton when you call `GameManager.Instance` after it's been destroyed? If so, do something like this instead:

```c#
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (isDestroyed) return null;

            // Your spawn logic...
        }
    }

    static bool isDestroyed;

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        isDestroyed = true;
    }
}
```